# Why using the most permissive setting won't allow request to get through?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-cors

I'm developing a web app with Flask & React and despite using Flask-CORS with
all the defaults unchanged (allowing for all headers and origins) requests made
from React gets rejected with `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/auth/check_passport. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Flask:

```
from flask_cors import CORS

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(current_config)
    from project.api.auth import auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    CORS(app)

    return app
```

In terminal I can see it makes it to Flask though: `127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2021 10:36:59] "POST /auth/check_passport HTTP/1.1" 200`

According to docs leaving CORS in its defaults allows for any client to reach the endpoint.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

**edit:**

auth.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request

auth_blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

@auth_blueprint.route('/check_passport', methods=['POST'])
def check_passport():
    print('called')  # isn't being printed out
    image_received = request.data['image']
    ...
    ...
```

front-end:

```
const checkPassport = () => {
    if (passportFile) {
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("image", passportFile, passportFile.name);
      const url = "http://localhost:5000/auth/check_passport";
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      };
      axios
        .post(url, fd, config)
        .then(resp => {
          console.log(resp.data.message);
          console.log(resp.data.content);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it might have something to do with you using blueprints, but no, I can't reproduce the problem. Here's my setup:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, jsonify

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/check_passport')
def check_passport():
    return jsonify(dict(message='Check passport'))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/auth')
CORS(app). # comment out to see cors error
```

I test it with this simple page making a request to the endpoint: (just drag it into a browser window and watch the console)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cors Check</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/check_passport';

            // fetch
            fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
                console.log('SUCCESS')
                console.log(data)
            })
            
            // or axios
            axios.get(url).then(response => {
                console.log('SUCCESS', response.data);
            })
        </script>
    </head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

I can see it working fine with `CORS(app)` but then without it doesn't.

Comment: I'm using `axios` which sends promise-based requests but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Mark you're right - it doesn't. Here, I've added an example of it working with axios request,

Comment: I'm POSTing to the endpoint. Please take a look at edit I've made to my question.

Comment: I've put a `print('called')` into the Flask route to see if the route is being triggered and I'm getting nothing in the terminal so something is blocking the route.

Comment: Requests started coming through as soon as I explicitly specified payload to be sent as data:  
`axios.post(url, {data : fd}, config).then(resp => {`   I thought it's sent as `data` by default.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!